# How to set the Width And Height of X & Y Axis of Bar Charts in Android AChartEngine?

Tags: android, graph, axis, bar-chart

I am new to Android AChartEngine.
I want to set the **width** and **height** of **X & Y Axes**.
I have tried, but I could not find the right solution for this.
I am using the code below:

```
public Intent execute(Context context) {
        String[] titles = new String[] { "2008", "2007" };
        List<double[]> values = new ArrayList<double[]>();
        values.add(new double[] { 14230, 12300, 14240, 15244, 15900, 19200,
                22030, 21200, 19500, 15500, 12600, 14000 });
        values.add(new double[] { 5230, 7300, 9240, 10540, 7900, 9200, 12030,
                11200, 9500, 10500, 11600, 13500 });
        int[] colors = new int[] { Color.BLUE, Color.CYAN };
        XYMultipleSeriesRenderer renderer = buildBarRenderer(colors);
        setChartSettings(renderer, "Monthly sales in the last 2 years",
                "Month", "Units sold", 0.5, 12.5, 0, 24000, Color.GRAY,
                Color.LTGRAY);
        renderer.getSeriesRendererAt(0).setDisplayChartValues(true);
        renderer.getSeriesRendererAt(1).setDisplayChartValues(true);
        renderer.setXLabels(12);
        renderer.setYLabels(10);
        renderer.setXLabelsAlign(Align.LEFT);
        renderer.setYLabelsAlign(Align.LEFT);
        renderer.setPanEnabled(true, false);
        renderer.setZoomRate(1.1f);
        renderer.setBarSpacing(0.5f);

        return ChartFactory.getBarChartIntent(context,
                buildBarDataset(titles, values), renderer, Type.STACKED);
    }
```

[image: Please see this image]

Comment: What do you mean by setting the width and height of the axes?

Answer (score 1):

You can give your own limit. For example if you want set limit to 0 to 100 for Y axis and 0 to 10 for X axis, you can change the code

**setChartSettings(renderer, "Monthly sales in the last 2 years", "Month", "Units sold", 1,

                   10, 0, 100, Color.GRAY, Color.LTGRAY);**

For X axis progress count 1,(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5)

**renderer.setXLabels(1);**

For Y axis progress count 10,(0, 10, 20, 30, .....100)

**renderer.setYLabels(10);**

And leave others as it is.

Hope this could be help you.